# Get stylesheet text from <link> tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i've got a sylesheet `<link>` tag:

```
<link rel=stylesheet href="/path/to/foo/bar.css" />
```

and i'd like to get the text of the `/path/to/foo/bar.css` stylesheet via javascript.

**is this possible?**  i'll even accept answers that don't work cross-browser...

***NOTE:*** answers involving `document.styleSheet` don't count, since the browser will have already transformed stuff like URL's, and i'm interested in the original source (even though this does provide an [interesting way to resolve URLs...](https://twitter.com/kriskowal/status/222825051274219521))

***ASLO NOTE:*** i'd prefer to do this w/o any xhr's

Comment: an XHR doesn't make a second request if the data's been cached.

Comment: @zzzzBov i updated the question to clarify that i'd like to do this w/o an xhr

Comment: and how do you expect to read a separate page without making a request for the data contained in said page? Unless you're using server side code to include the contents of the file inline (which seems like a poor decision) you'll be required to make an XHR (or use an iframe, which is more annoying than an XHR).

Answer (score 4):

Simply do an AJAX request to the specified URL.

Using jQuery:

```
$.get('/path/to/foo/bar.css', function(CSS_text) {
    // Just use the CSS_text here...
});
```

You can easily do the same with native JS...

Comment: yeah, xhr is an option, but it's a pain b/c this is bootstrap code w/o jquery.  i'd like something that's synchronous and doesn't involve any xhr's, but if i don't get any other suitable answers you may get credit for this one....

Comment: @aaronstacy, asynchronous reads are the way to go, using a synchronous XHR could work but would likely cause unnecessary delays for the user.

Comment: @zzzzBov as my updated in the question states, i don't want to have to make another request for this, so i'd prefer to do this w/o any xhr's, async or otherwise

Comment: @aaronstacy - If your server is set up correctly, your browser should be caching that file, so that any subsequent requests wouldn't actually go to the server.